# Keras Image Classification - Prediction accuracy on validation dataset does not match val_acc

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to **classify a set of images within two categories**: *left* and *right*.

I built a CNN using Keras, my classifier seems to work well:

- I have 1,939 images used for training (50% *left*, 50% *right*)
- I have 648 images used for validation (50% *left*, 50% *right*)
- All images are 115x45, in greyscale
- **acc** is increasing up to 99.53%
- **val_acc** is increasing up to 98.38%
- Both **loss** and **val_loss** are converging close to 0

**Keras verbose looks normal to me:**

```
60/60 [==============================] - 6s 98ms/step - loss: 0.6295 - acc: 0.6393 - val_loss: 0.4877 - val_acc: 0.7641
Epoch 2/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 78ms/step - loss: 0.4825 - acc: 0.7734 - val_loss: 0.3403 - val_acc: 0.8799
Epoch 3/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 77ms/step - loss: 0.3258 - acc: 0.8663 - val_loss: 0.2314 - val_acc: 0.9042
Epoch 4/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 83ms/step - loss: 0.2498 - acc: 0.8942 - val_loss: 0.2329 - val_acc: 0.9042
Epoch 5/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 76ms/step - loss: 0.2408 - acc: 0.9002 - val_loss: 0.1426 - val_acc: 0.9432
Epoch 6/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 80ms/step - loss: 0.1968 - acc: 0.9260 - val_loss: 0.1484 - val_acc: 0.9367
Epoch 7/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 77ms/step - loss: 0.1621 - acc: 0.9319 - val_loss: 0.1141 - val_acc: 0.9578
Epoch 8/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 81ms/step - loss: 0.1600 - acc: 0.9361 - val_loss: 0.1229 - val_acc: 0.9513
Epoch 9/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 70ms/step - loss: 0.1358 - acc: 0.9462 - val_loss: 0.0884 - val_acc: 0.9692
Epoch 10/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 74ms/step - loss: 0.1193 - acc: 0.9542 - val_loss: 0.1232 - val_acc: 0.9529
Epoch 11/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 79ms/step - loss: 0.1075 - acc: 0.9595 - val_loss: 0.0865 - val_acc: 0.9724
Epoch 12/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 73ms/step - loss: 0.1209 - acc: 0.9531 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_acc: 0.9497
Epoch 13/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 73ms/step - loss: 0.1135 - acc: 0.9609 - val_loss: 0.0860 - val_acc: 0.9838
Epoch 14/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 70ms/step - loss: 0.0869 - acc: 0.9682 - val_loss: 0.0907 - val_acc: 0.9675
Epoch 15/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step - loss: 0.0960 - acc: 0.9637 - val_loss: 0.0996 - val_acc: 0.9643
Epoch 16/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 73ms/step - loss: 0.0951 - acc: 0.9625 - val_loss: 0.1223 - val_acc: 0.9481
Epoch 17/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 70ms/step - loss: 0.0685 - acc: 0.9729 - val_loss: 0.1220 - val_acc: 0.9513
Epoch 18/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 73ms/step - loss: 0.0791 - acc: 0.9715 - val_loss: 0.0959 - val_acc: 0.9692
Epoch 19/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step - loss: 0.0595 - acc: 0.9802 - val_loss: 0.0648 - val_acc: 0.9773
Epoch 20/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step - loss: 0.0486 - acc: 0.9844 - val_loss: 0.0691 - val_acc: 0.9838
Epoch 21/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 70ms/step - loss: 0.0499 - acc: 0.9812 - val_loss: 0.1166 - val_acc: 0.9627
Epoch 22/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step - loss: 0.0481 - acc: 0.9844 - val_loss: 0.0875 - val_acc: 0.9734
Epoch 23/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 70ms/step - loss: 0.0533 - acc: 0.9814 - val_loss: 0.1094 - val_acc: 0.9724
Epoch 24/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 70ms/step - loss: 0.0487 - acc: 0.9812 - val_loss: 0.0722 - val_acc: 0.9740
Epoch 25/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 72ms/step - loss: 0.0441 - acc: 0.9828 - val_loss: 0.0992 - val_acc: 0.9773
Epoch 26/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step - loss: 0.0667 - acc: 0.9726 - val_loss: 0.0964 - val_acc: 0.9643
Epoch 27/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 73ms/step - loss: 0.0436 - acc: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.0771 - val_acc: 0.9708
Epoch 28/32
60/60 [==============================] - 4s 71ms/step - loss: 0.0322 - acc: 0.9896 - val_loss: 0.0872 - val_acc: 0.9756
Epoch 29/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 80ms/step - loss: 0.0294 - acc: 0.9943 - val_loss: 0.1414 - val_acc: 0.9578
Epoch 30/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 76ms/step - loss: 0.0348 - acc: 0.9870 - val_loss: 0.1102 - val_acc: 0.9659
Epoch 31/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 76ms/step - loss: 0.0306 - acc: 0.9922 - val_loss: 0.0794 - val_acc: 0.9659
Epoch 32/32
60/60 [==============================] - 5s 76ms/step - loss: 0.0152 - acc: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.1051 - val_acc: 0.9724
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 113, 43, 32)       896
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 21, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 54, 19, 32)        9248
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 27, 9, 32)         0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 7776)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               995456
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129
=================================================================
Total params: 1,005,729
Trainable params: 1,005,729
Non-trainable params: 0
```

So everything looks great, but **when I tried to predict the category of 2,000 samples I got very strange results, with an accuracy < 70%**.

At first I thought this sample might be biased, so I tried, instead, to predict the images in the validation dataset.

I should have a 98.38% accuracy, and a perfect 50-50 split, but instead, once again I got:

- 170 images predicted right, instead of 324, with an accuracy of 98.8%
- 478 images predicted left, instead of 324, with an accuracy of 67.3%
- Average accuracy: 75.69% and not 98.38%

I guess something is wrong either in my CNN or my prediction script.

**CNN classifier code:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

# Init CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (115, 45, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = False)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (115, 45),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('./dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (115, 45),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 1939/32, # total samples / batch size
                         epochs = 32,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 648/32)

# Save the classifier
classifier.evaluate_generator(generator=test_set)
classifier.summary()
classifier.save('./classifier.h5')
```

**Prediction code:**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from shutil import copyfile

classifier = load_model('./classifier.h5')
folder = './small/'
files = os.listdir(folder)
pleft = 0
pright = 0
for f in files:
    test_image = image.load_img(folder+f, target_size = (115, 45))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = classifier.predict(test_image)
        #print training_set.class_indices
    if result[0][0] == 1:
        pright=pright+1
        prediction = 'right'
        copyfile(folder+'../'+f, '/found_right/'+f)
    else:
        prediction = 'left'
        copyfile(folder+'../'+f, '/found_left/'+f)
        pleft=pleft+1

ptot = pleft + pright
print 'Left = '+str(pleft)+' ('+str(pleft / (ptot / 100))+'%)'
print 'Right = '+str(pright)
print 'Total = '+str(ptot)
```

**Output:**

```
Left = 478 (79%)
Right = 170
Total = 648
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done a lot of training with a generator, but your accuracy is suspiciously high on the first epoch, with only 60 images per batch, my best guess is that is it overfitting on a batch-by-batch basis. But I am not overly confident in this. Try maybe to run with bigger batches?

Comment: You aren't using the model predictions correctly, comparing the output of the model to 1 does not make any sense, you need to use a tunable threshold (keras uses 0.5 to compute accuracy).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I double-checked and in my case Keras' output is always [[1.]] or [[0.]], I read this could be related to the activation function used.

Comment: @Tacratis, Tried this without luck, however what did improve the situation was increasing the validation_steps. I don't understand why, as per Keras documentation  : "It should typically be equal to the number of samples of your validation dataset divided by the batch size". Also, I noticed the val_loss is plateauing while acc_loss keeps decreasing which would be a sign of overfitting. Are there any tweaks to prevent this?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you observed, Keras computes accuracy by thresholding the output value at 0.5. If you print the values they might be rounded and that's why you see 1.0 instead of 0.99999. Also its bad practice to compare floating point numbers for equality.

Comment: Also you are not rescaling (dividing by 255) your image values while predicting, while the generator is doing this for you.

Comment: Indeed @MatiasValdenegro was right, after rescaling I got better results. Still had a high val_loss which I resolved with Dropout() and EarlyStopping. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by doing two things:

1. As @Matias Valdenegro suggested, I had to **rescale the image values before predicting**, I added *test_image /= 255.* before calling predict().
2. As my val_loss was still a bit high, I added an **EarlyStopping callback** as well as two **Dropout()** before my Dense layers.

My prediction results are now consistent with the ones obtained during training/validation.